# phantomjs unable to load files which its path contains non-ascii characters

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

Trying to load a local file with path

> "file:///C:/phantom/ŞUBAT-2015-1.xhtml"

containing non-ascii chars, gives this exception:

> unable to load url: "file:///C:/phantom/?UBAT-2015-1.xhtml"

How can make phantomjs to locate the file?

By the way, can not change the file name.

**A note**: in script, trying something like this : **require('fs').write("filename.txt", path, 'w')** puts the right filename into filename.txt

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yavu could you please add more code to your question? (It's a little bit hard to figure out what's going wrong without know more of the context)

That being said, you could try using the flag `--web-security=false` to allow phantomjs to access your local files while in the context of another page. You can run `phantomjs --web-security=false yourScript.js` on the command line to try that out.